# Android thread sleep inputted by user

Tags: android, time, thread-sleep

I have a input box which the users set a time for the delay. Is it possible set delay time by user input in android?

Comment: Can you please post your code by editing your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly just wanting the user to input an integer you could do the following:

```
EditText tv = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

Thread.Sleep(Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString());

}
});
```

Obviously the code above needs to be changed to fit your app (and checked for errors) but that is the general gist of the solution. You could check the user input for validation too.

Comment: @user3437592 You'll have to be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: Is impossible to set getText to tv!

Comment: @user3437592 EditText views have the method getText(), the above code should work.